# The top-level auxiliary file: document.aux I found no \citation commands

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am trying to use biber for a simple report but I am getting

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Debian) The top-level auxiliary file: document.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file document.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file document.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file document.aux (There were 3 error messages)

in Texmaker.

These are the last few lines of the log:

```
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 13.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 13.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'a' on page 1 undefined on input line 16.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 18.
[1
{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./document.aux)
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex) document
(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'document.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `document.run.xml'.
)
```

I don't quite understand what's wrong here.

**document.tex**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}


This is \cite{DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1301-3781}

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

**references.bib**

```
@article{DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1301-3781,
  author    = {Tomas Mikolov and
               Kai Chen and
               Greg Corrado and
               Jeffrey Dean},
  title     = {Efficient Estimation of Word Representations in Vector Space},
  journal   = {CoRR},
  volume    = {abs/1301.3781},
  year      = {2013},
  url       = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3781},
  timestamp = {Thu, 07 May 2015 20:02:01 +0200},
  biburl    = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/journals/corr/abs-1301-3781},
  bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, http://dblp.org}
}
```

Comment: The error message shows that you are actually running BibTeX and not Biber. See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) on how to run Biber from your editor.

Comment: Any news here? Did the linked question help?